# How to display or print all images inside a directory using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Im new in cakephp, I appreciate any help

```
 <?php
       $dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . '/img/profile/'.$profile);
       $files = $dir->find('.*', true);

       pr($files);exit;
     ?>
```

**output below**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.png
    [1] => 20643696_1656261664406406_1426837475_n.jpg
    [2] => IMG_2911.JPG
    [3] => h.png
    [4] => 5.jpg
)
```

I dont know how to print the images by looping.

I can echo 1 image inside in directory

```
echo $this->Html->image('profile/' .$br.$profile.$br.stream_get_contents($users->profile_pic),array('width'=>'250px','height'=>'250px'));
```

profile_pic is the image field in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the actual images you can make something like this:

```
foreach($files as $file){
  echo "<img src='./img/profile/$profile/$file'>";
}
```

Note that you should check if the file is really a image (png, jpg, gif and so on)

If you just want to print the names, you can make something like this:

```
foreach($files as $file){
      echo $file . "<br>"; // The br is optional
}
```

Updated: Just remove the stream_get_contents:

```
echo $this->Html->image('profile/' .$br.$profile.$br.$file);
```

Comment: stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given [APP/Template\Users\profile.ctp, line 54] echo $this->Html->image('profile/' .$br.$profile.$br.stream_get_contents($file));

Comment: $users->profile_pic is the image's name or what type is it?

Comment: yes name of the field of the image profile_pic everytime i change profile_pic the image is in the directory of the current user.

Comment: I have updated my answer. The stream_get_contents is not necessary